# Link to Magento Admin section in email template

Tags: email, magento, admin

Every time a customer makes a new order I need to send an email to the Administrator with the link to the ADMIN order detail section to access directly. For example:

http://www.mydomain.com.ar/index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/19/key/72977b31f74180d25ba185a1cfe86d5a/

How can I achieve this?
Thanks you very much for any help

Answer (score 0):

Bcc in the admin email in System > configuration > Sales emails > Orders etc

Comment: And how to create the link that redirects me to the admin section?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
use Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface;

...

    private UrlInterface $url;
...
    public function __construct(
        ...
        UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        ...
        $this->url = $url;
    }
...
        $url = $this->url->getUrl('sales_order/view', ['order_id' => $order->getId()])
...
```